# Graphs with exactly $n$ perfect matchings

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Is there for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ a connected, simple, undirected graph $G_n=(V_n,E_n)$ such that $G_n$ has exactly $n$ perfect matchings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will let the picture speak for itself.

[image]

Comment: @wojowu Think you can make for $n^2$ at every $n>5$?

Comment: @Freeman. For $n^2$ what? If you want a graph with $n^2$ matchings, replace $n,n-1$ in my construction with $n^2,n^2-1$.

Comment: @Wojowu No graph has to have $2n$ vertices.

Comment: @Freeman. http://prntscr.com/kxpgs3 $2n+2$ vertices

Comment: @Wojowu I think that graph has $n$ perfect matchings; the top and bottom choices are not independent (and in fact must be the same).

Comment: Add in the zig-zag (and make it cyclic) and it should work, I think.

Comment: @user44191 Good point and fix. Thank you.

Comment: @Wojowu It has $n^2$ matchings? Damn is there trick for every $n^k$ with $k$ fixed in $\mathbb Z$ and $\forall n$ large enough?

Comment: @Freeman. If you forget about being connected, you can just take $k$ disjoint copies of the graph from my answer. It should be possible to connect them using some additional vertices which don't impact the number of matchings.

Comment: @Wojowu Preferably $c\cdot n+O(1)$ vertices where $c$ independent of $n,k$ and connected.

Comment: Connected shouldn't matter; just connect all copies at the "top" point. These edges can't be used in a matching. Making the coefficient of $n$ independent of $k$ would be more difficult, though - I'd suspect impossible.